# mostrar un registro de tres tablas relacionadas

Tags: sql, server

hola alguien me podria ayudar tengo tres tablas relacionadas estas serian las siguientes.
productos
id
descripcion
idcategoria

categorias
id
descripción

ventas
idproducto
fecha_venta

mi pregunta es la tabla ventas tiene miles de registros y lo q necesito hacer es mostrar el nombre de la categoria con la ultima venta como podría hacer esto con una instrucción sql, gracias por las respuestas.

Comment: Considera indicar qué motor de bases de datos usas

Answer (score 1):

```
--Con la instrucción TOP 1 se obtiene el primer registro devuelto 
--por la consulta
SELECT TOP 1 c.descripcion, v.fecha_venta 
FROM ventas v 
-- Se hace un join de la tabla venta con la tabla productos
--para obtener el idcategoria del producto vendido, luego
--se hace join con la tabla categorias usando el idcategoria del producto
JOIN productos p on p.id = v.idproducto
JOIN categorias c on c.id = p.idcategoria
--Se ordena por la fecha de la venta de forma descendente, eso pone la última 
--venta como primer registro devuelto
 ORDER BY v.fecha_venta desc
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta tenia una ligera sospecha de que pudiera ser asi la respuesta, pero mejor quise postearlo para estar seguro de que no hay otra manera de hacerlo el motor es sql server.

Answer (score 1):

Me ganó el usuario de arriba, pero creo que igual puedo complementar con algo.
Este es mi código:

```
select top 1 c.descripcion as "CATEGORIA", v.idproducto as "ID PRODUCTO"
from [SOF registro 3 tablas].dbo.categorias c
left join [SOF registro 3 tablas].dbo.productos p on c.id = p.idCategoria
left join [SOF registro 3 tablas].dbo.ventas v on p.id = v.idproducto
where v.fecha_ventas = 
    (select max(vi.fecha_ventas)
    from [SOF registro 3 tablas].dbo.ventas vi
    )
order by v.idproducto desc;
```

Y me preocupé de insertar dos registros con la misma fecha. Aprendí dos cosas de ello, la primera es que las milésimas son 3, pero solo se pueden editar 2; y lo segundo es que, en caso de que hasta las milésimas sean iguales, devuelta el último registro insertado en la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta todo aporte sirve tenia una leve sospecha de que asi era pero queria estar seguro que no había otra manera sin usar el top 1

Comment: Y si había otra manera, la sentencia anidada mía con max() podía ser reemplazada por el order by con el top 1. Cuando vi que crrlos lo hizo así, me di cuenta que su consulta era más simple y, en vez de hacer dos subconsultas (para fecha_ventas e idproducto), combiné ambos estilos. n.n